I can't ws:// connect to the docker container I put on the server
After completing the test via apic on my laptop, I put it up as a docker container on awsec2 Ubuntu server, but it doesn't connect.
Just in case, I tried to do the same by putting the container on the local with a docker, but it connects normally.
I don't know why I can't connect when there is no separate error code in the server log.
I opened the server 8080 port, and the restapi http:// connection works well. But the ws:// connection is not working.
Only containers uploaded from the server are not connected, so what's the problem..
This command was created when uploading docker containers.
docker run -d -e PORT=8080 -p 8080:8080 --name test-server --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway --restart always imagename

WebConfig

@Configuration

public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String CORS_URL_PATTERN = "/*";

    private static final String CORS_URL = "*";

    private static final String CORS_METHOD = "*";

    @Override

    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping(CORS_URL_PATTERN)

                .allowedOrigins(CORS_URL)

                .allowedMethods(CORS_METHOD);

    }

}


WebSocketConfig

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}


connection success(localhost)




connection fail (server ip)



